# How to write array of string values from Pandas to Google Big Query

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

Im currently trying to write a Pandas Dataframe (Python 3.x) into Google Big Query. The table has a column with dtype object that contains an array of string values.

[sample of pandas table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2YIC.png)
I aim to create a BQ table that maintains a nested table structure as below:
[sample of Big Query table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPhEh.png)
with following schema:
[schema of Big Query table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG3Dc.png)

Im using the [google-cloud-bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#loading_a_pandas_dataframe_to_a_table) library as that allows the df to convert to the Parquet format that per documentation supports nested array values:

code used:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = 'dataset.table'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema = [
            bigquery.SchemaField('route_id', 'INTEGER'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('types', 'STRING', mode='REPEATED')
    ], 
    writeDisposition="WRITE_APPEND"
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, 
    table_id, 
    job_config=job_config,
)

# Wait for the load job to complete.
job.result()
```

but unfortunately Im getting the following error message returned:

> BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Provided
>   schema is not compatible with the file
>   'prod-scotty-76a528bc-407d-4224-8951-c8ff0c71faa1'. Field 'types' is
>   specified as REPEATED in provided schema which does not match NULLABLE
>   as specified in the file.

What has been tried so far:

1. used RECORD field type

but that caused the following error:
https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/21

2. not shipping any schema in python at all (and allow Python/BQ to sort it out themselves)

surprisingly this works for the first iteration (CREATE_IF_NEEDED)creating a table in BQ that maintained the nested structure with the following schema automatically applied:
[auto-applied schema of BQ table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URpkU.png), but fails if you try to append even the exact table again returning the same error as under 1.

Any advise or tips?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be [a mismatch](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/17#issuecomment-531777464) between the schema in parquet and the interpreted schema for arrays when you load the data to BigQuery that has not been resolved yet.

I have been able to properly upload a dataframe with an array by using the open-source library [pandas-gcp](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq

d = {'nested_string': [['hi', 'keloke'], ['io', 'ready']], 'route_id': [83833, 4487]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

table_id = "dataset.table"
project_id = 'my_project'

pandas_gbq.to_gbq(
    df, table_id, project_id=project_id, if_exists='replace',
)
```

Other possible workarounds without 3rd party tools:

· Use Dataflow instead

· From the python file, save the dataframe as a csv in a Google Storage Bucket and have it ingested from BigQuery

Do you think any of this could work for you?

Comment: Thanks Albert! 

I tried a similar approach with pandas_gbq library, but the approach only worked if the table didnt exist yet. I see you replace the table in the event it exists. Keen to know if your approach also works if you try to append to an existing table in BQ?

For now I have bypassed the issue by
a) re-format array from `[a,b,c]` to `a,b,c` in pandas df
b) write it back to BQ as string
c) use the SPLIT string function https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split in BQ itself to restore the nested schema
d) store the table
thanks though

Comment: It worked for me with the table previously created on BQ (empty). Now I also tried to append (if_exists = 'append') and it added the new rows to the existing ones.

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Comment: This only works with if_exists="replace" as it creates a new table with repeated column treated as a string (nested_string in your case).

Comment: When you set [if_exists="append"] what is the observed behaviour?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, when I use if_exists='replace' pandas_gbq creates again the table treating the repeated column as a string. If use if_exists='append' I get this error:
google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)

Comment: When I run the given code snipper I am getting an error " ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'list' object"